# helm airflow error , I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-helm

```
helm install airflow-staging airflow-stable/airflow --version “7.14.0” --namespace staging  --set airflow.config.AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__GIT_BRANCH=master --set dags.git.ref=“https://github.com/pedaling/class101-airflow.git” --values staging-values.yaml
```

it gives this error --

> Error: failed to download "airflow-stable/airflow" at version "“7.14.0”" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

so I type the `helm repo update` then it return --

> Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
> ...Successfully got an update from the "airflow-stable" chart repository
> Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈

even I typed `helm repo update` it always return the same error like

> Error: failed to download "airflow-stable/airflow" at version "“7.14.0”" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

To install the `stable/airflow` follow the steps from the repo README:
https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow

I have copied the relevant section below.

---

#### 1 - Add the Repo:

```sh
helm repo add airflow-stable https://airflow-helm.github.io/charts
helm repo update
```

#### 2 - Install the Chart:

> ⚠️ find values for `CHART_VERSION` under [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/releases)

```sh
export RELEASE_NAME=my-airflow-cluster # set a name!
export NAMESPACE=my-airflow-namespace # set a namespace!
export CHART_VERSION=8.X.X # set a version!
export VALUES_FILE=./custom-values.yaml # set your values file path!

# Helm 3
helm install \
  $RELEASE_NAME \
  airflow-stable/airflow \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --version $CHART_VERSION \
  --values $VALUES_FILE

# Helm 2
helm install \
  airflow-stable/airflow \
  --name $RELEASE_NAME \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --version $CHART_VERSION \
  --values $VALUES_FILE
```

#### 3 - Access the WebUI

> ⚠️ browse to http://localhost:8080 after running the following commands

```sh
export NAMESPACE=my-airflow-namespace # set a namespace!

export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace $NAMESPACE -l "component=web,app=airflow" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
kubectl port-forward --namespace $NAMESPACE $POD_NAME 8080:8080
```

**NOTE:**

- default credentials -- user: **admin** - password: **admin**

Comment: sorry i am now to this so i wanted to ask how to execute multiline commands in command prompt like


```# Helm 3
helm install \
  $RELEASE_NAME \
  airflow-stable/airflow \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  --version $CHART_VERSION \
  --values $VALUES_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why that error is generated (maybe to old version) but I experienced the same by running

```
helm upgrade airflow -f values.yaml airflow-stable/airflow --version airflow-7.16.0
```

**Solution:**
Go to [GitHub Releases](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/releases)

**1.** Find your release, mine for example is 7.16.0 and copy link to its `.tgz`

```
https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/releases/download/airflow-7.16.0/airflow-7.16.0.tgz
```

**2.** Execute `helm pull` to your local directory

```
helm pull https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/releases/download/airflow-7.16.0/airflow-7.16.0.tgz
```

**3.** And finaly upgrade using local chart

```
helm upgrade airflow -f values.yaml airflow-7.16.0.tgz
```